# Html table into JQgrid with table classes

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

my html table as below

```
<table id="mytable">
 <tr><th> ID </th></tr>
 <tr class="danger"><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr class="info"><td>10</td></tr>
 <tr class="warning"><td>7</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using jqgrid I converted my table into jqgrid as below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     tableToGrid("#mytable",{
      autowidth: true
  });
  });
```

but when I refresh page my table converted into jqgrid but my tr classes not presents in new  converted table . How I should add my tr classes in jqgrid

JS fiddle link as below 
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_0586/FkBZq/)

Comment: if possible give us fiddle link

Comment: Hi @PandiyanCool I added jsfiddle link in above edited question. In above demo my class name remove when table converted to jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your table with jqgrid, it will automatically take out all the calss from your table and it will add it own classes all the way. Suppose if you want to modify your header style you need to overwrite their classes only. In your case, you need to use the following class.

```
 .ui-th-column{
   color:red;
 }
```

If you add the above, it will modify the header style for all the jqgrid tables. If you want to restrict to only this table, then you need to add parent div then refer your class like below. Assume that i have a parent div with id called "sampletablediv"

```
 #sampletablediv .ui-th-column{
   color:red;
 }
```

[**Have a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FkBZq/2/)

Comment: Hi its my mistake I changes my js fiddle link as http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_0586/FkBZq/3/

Comment: oh ok. So this is fixed or dynamic table. I mean it will be only three rows or many.

Comment: it is dynamic table, row generated dynamically if first td of all rows contains following data then classes changes dynamically if td = cell 11 then tr class danger, td = cell 21 then tr class warning and if td = cell 31 then tr class info

Comment: so you are assigning only for first 3 rows. after that no classes assigning. am i right?

Comment: no no if any tr first td having above criteria then according to td data tr classes will be changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55554/discussion-between-yogesh-and-suresh-ponnukalai).